# How to send CSRF Token from jqgrid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using PHP 7, Cake, JQuery and JQGrid 4.4.0 to create/edit a table.

The table is displayed correctly with the proper data.

The correct behaviour of the table is like this:

1. The table is displayed with data
2. I select one data row in the table by clicking it
3. I press a button to display a modal with the selected row's info
4. I modify any data in the modal
5. I press the save button
6. The data is saved correctly

However, when I press the save button, I get an error of an Invalid or Non-Existent CSRF Token.

Originally the table is defined like this:

```
$("#tabla_tx").jqGrid({  
    autowidth: true,            
    colNames:['idProyecto','IdMovil','Nombre Movil', 'Comuna', 'Region','ZONA','Area','Proyecto','A&ntilde;o Proyecto',
              'Estado Plan', 'Sub-Estado Plan','BW Plan','Estado (Movil)','OTT','Estado OTT','BW OTT','PEP OTT',
              'Imputaci&oacute;n OTT','Fecha Est30','A&ntilde;o Est30','Mes Est30', 'Week Est30','Tipo de Acceso',
              'Nombre Resp. Control','Prioridad', 'Fecha Entrega Parcial','A&ntilde;o Entrega Parcial',
              'Mes Entrega Parcial','Week Entrega Parcial','WPlan','WFET','BW Entrega','Fecha Entrega','Ano Entrega',
              'Mes Entrega','Week Entrega', 'Responsable (UC)','Condicion Actual (Problema)','Problema (Nombre Resp.)',
              'Responsable Actual (Unidad Responsable)','Gerencia Resp','Nuevo Responsable',
              'Descripcion Condicion Actual','FET Hito','Comentario','Supervisor UM',
              'Contratista','OPR1','Salto1','TICKET1','OPR2','Salto2','TICKET2','Ticket Instalacion 1',
              'Ticket Instalacion 2','Ticket Retiro 1','Ticket Retiro 2','Ticket Router','BW Actual',
              'Observacion 1','Observacion 2','Actividad a Ejecutar','Nuevo PE','Cambio de PE','PE.Actual','PE.Final',
              'Shelf','Slot','Tipo de tarjeta','SIUs','RFI Formalizado','RFI Estado','Ticket Tx',
              'Plan','Tecnologia','Activ.Infraestructura','Numero TP','Estado TP','Fecha TP','PM',
              'FET','% Avance Semana Actual', 'Ingenieria (20%)', 'Permisos (20%)', 'Instalacion Acceso (20%)', 
              'Equipos TX (20%)', 'Pruebas y PEM (20%)'],       
    colModel :[{
        name:'dato0', 
        index:'dato0' ,
        align: 'left',  
        hidden:true,  
        editable: true, 
        editoptions:{visible: false}},
                {name:'dato1', index:'dato1' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, editoptions:{disabled: false, 
                 style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato2', index:'dato2' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width: 250, editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato3', index:'dato3' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_comunas}},
                {name:'dato4', index:'dato4' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px",value:datos_region}},
                {name:'dato5', index:'dato5' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px",value:datos_zonas}},
                {name:'dato86', index:'dato86' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato6', index:'dato6' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width: 250, editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_proyectos}},
                {name:'dato7', index:'dato7' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_anos}},
                {name:'dato8', index:'dato8' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_estadoplan}},
                {name:'dato9', index:'dato9' ,   align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_subestadoplan}},
                {name:'dato10', index:'dato10' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato11', index:'dato11' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_estadomovil}},
                {name:'dato12', index:'dato12' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato13', index:'dato13' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_estadoott}},
                {name:'dato14', index:'dato14' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato76', index:'dato76' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato77', index:'dato77' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato22', index:'dato22' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",
                              dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})}}},
                {name:'dato23', index:'dato23' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato24', index:'dato24' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true, style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato25', index:'dato25' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},                                                    
                {name:'dato21', index:'dato21' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_tipoacceso}},
                {name:'dato28', index:'dato28' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width:250, editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_responsablecontrol}},
                {name:'dato67', index:'dato67' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_prioridad}},
                {name:'dato29', index:'dato29' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",
                              dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})}}},
                {name:'dato30', index:'dato30' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato31', index:'dato31' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato32', index:'dato32' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato68', index:'dato68' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato20', index:'dato20' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato15', index:'dato15' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato16', index:'dato16' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",
                              dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})}}},
                {name:'dato17', index:'dato17' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato18', index:'dato18' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato19', index:'dato19' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px"}},                   
                {name:'dato33', index:'dato33' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato26', index:'dato26' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_problema}},
                {name:'dato35', index:'dato35' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_nombreresponsable}},
                {name:'dato27', index:'dato27' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width:250, editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px",value:datos_unidadresponsable}},
                {name:'dato34', index:'dato34' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true,style: "width: 250px",value:datos_gerenciaresponsable}},
                {name:'dato52', index:'dato52' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width:250, editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato53', index:'dato53' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width:300, editable: true,edittype:"textarea", 
                 editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"20",style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato54', index:'dato54' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato55', index:'dato55' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  width:300, editable: true,edittype:"textarea", 
                 editoptions:{rows:"3",cols:"20",style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato63', index:'dato63' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_supervisorum}},
                {name:'dato64', index:'dato64' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_contratista}},
                {name:'dato36', index:'dato36' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato37', index:'dato37' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato38', index:'dato38' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato39', index:'dato39' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato40', index:'dato40' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato41', index:'dato41' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato42', index:'dato42' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato43', index:'dato43' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato44', index:'dato44' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato45', index:'dato45' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato46', index:'dato46' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato47', index:'dato47' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px", value:datos_banda}},
                {name:'dato48', index:'dato48' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato49', index:'dato49' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato50', index:'dato50' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato51', index:'dato51' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px", value:datos_pe}},
                {name:'dato59', index:'dato59' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_cambiope}},
                {name:'dato60', index:'dato60' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px", value:datos_pe}},
                {name:'dato61', index:'dato61' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px", value:datos_pe}},
                {name:'dato56', index:'dato56' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato58', index:'dato58' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_slot}},
                {name:'dato57', index:'dato57' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_tipotarjeta}},
                {name:'dato62', index:'dato62' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_sius}},
                {name:'dato65', index:'dato65' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",
                              dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})}}},
                {name:'dato69', index:'dato69' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_rftestado}},
                {name:'dato66', index:'dato66' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato70', index:'dato70' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_plan}},
                {name:'dato71', index:'dato71' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_tecnologia}},
                {name:'dato72', index:'dato72' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_actividad_infraestructura}},
                {name:'dato73', index:'dato73' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato74', index:'dato74' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_estado_tp}},
                {name:'dato75', index:'dato75' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",
                              dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})}}},
                {name:'dato78', index:'dato78' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{disabled: true, style: "width: 250px"}},
                {name:'dato79', index:'dato79' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",
                              dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})}}},
                {name:'dato80', index:'dato80' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_porcentajes}},
                {name:'dato81', index:'dato81' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_porcentajes}},
                {name:'dato82', index:'dato82' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_porcentajes}},
                {name:'dato83', index:'dato83' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_porcentajes}},
                {name:'dato84', index:'dato84' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_porcentajes}},
                {name:'dato85', index:'dato85' , align: 'left',  hidden:false,  editable: true, edittype:'select', 
                 editoptions:{style: "width: 250px",value:datos_porcentajes}}
    ],
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
    paging: true,
    loadonce:false,
    pager:jQuery('#pager_tx'),
    datatype: "jsonstring",             
    datastr: data,
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [50,100,500,1000,5000],
    viewrecords: true,  
    caption: 'Proyectos de Transmisi&oacute;n e Inbuilding - SubGerencia de Proyectos de Acceso', 
    editurl:$("#urlActualizar").val().replace("param", area),
    height: '410'
});
jQuery("#tabla_tx").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager_tx',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false});
jQuery("#tabla_tx").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false}); 
jQuery("#tabla_tx").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager_tx',{caption:"Excel", 
    onClickButton:function(){ 
        $(location).attr('href',$("#urlExcel").val()); 
    }}
);
```

Based in the solutions explained in [How to pass csrf_token to the post params of editurl of jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476100/how-to-pass-csrf-token-to-the-post-params-of-editurl-of-jqgrid) and [passing csrf token through jqgrid on cell edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326145/passing-csrf-token-through-jqgrid-on-cell-edit/29428499#29428499), I added the following lines of code to the jqGrid's options with no avail:

```
loadBeforeSend: function(jqxhr){
    jqxhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content'));
},
editData: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content')
},
postData: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content')
},
ajaxEditOptions:{
    beforeSend: function(jqxhr){
        jqxhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content'));
    }
},
ajaxGridOptions:{
    beforeSend: function(jqxhr){
        jqxhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content'));
    }
},
ajaxRowOptions:{
    beforeSend: function(jqxhr){
        jqxhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content'));
    }
},
ajaxSelectOptions:{
    beforeSend: function(jqxhr){
        jqxhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content'));
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there something I must add/change to avoid this problem?
2. On the mentioned pages someone solved the same problem with the following lines of code. Are these applicable to my problem?

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
   if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
      $(selector).restoreRow(lastSel); 
      lastSel=id; 
   }

 var editparameters = {
    extraparam: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('.token-data').data('token')},
    keys: true,
  };
 $(selector).jqGrid('editRow', id, editparameters);
}
```

3. According to http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events, what is the proper event to establish the CSRF token if it is not beforeSend?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

According to Horst Walter's solution in [How to set request header to the ajax object for jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706579/how-to-set-request-header-to-the-ajax-object-for-jqgrid), you must add the following Javascript lines of code in the page with the jqgrid table using the JQuery's `ajaxSetup` function:

```
var csrfHeader=""; //Your CSRF header here
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
        'X-CSRF-Token' : csrfHeader
    }
});
```

In my case, I put the header in a `<meta>` tag in my page. For those who are using PHP with cakephp 4, like me, this can be done adding the following line inside the `<head>` section of the page:

```
<?= $this->Html->meta('csrfToken', $this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken')) ?>
```

And then asign the value of the `<meta>` tag to the javascript variable. For those who are using JQuery, this can be don with the following line:

```
var csrfHeader=$('meta[name="csrfToken"]').attr('content');
```

Thanks anyway :-D